# Creating a template & using variables to replace in JS

Tags: javascript, templates, scope

I'm creating some functionality with our charts/graphs (using chart.js) which will allow the user to select what time scale they want to see. I've created something which works; but as we have 4 different graphs, I don't want to create an enormous, inefficient document by reusing this code and then finding & replacing the parts which have changed. Instead, I would like to create a template object which is created once, and then replace the templated/generic variable names with that graph's own properties.

Here is a condensed version of the code I created:

```
        $("#engagementDaily").hide();
        $("#engagementWeekly").hide();
        $("#engagementMonthly").hide();
        $("#engagementYearly").hide();
        $("#engagementDay").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'day'
            $(this).addClass('active');
            nullXAxes();
            $("#engagementDaily").fadeIn();
            $("#engagementWeekly").hide();
            $("#engagementMonthly").hide();
            $("#engagementYearly").hide();
            engGraph.update();
        });
        $("#engagementWeek").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'week'
            $(this).addClass('active');
            nullXAxes();
            $("#engagementDaily").hide();
            $("#engagementWeekly").fadeIn();
            $("#engagementMonthly").hide();
            $("#engagementYearly").hide();
            engGraph.update();
        });
        $("#engagementMonth").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'month'
            $(this).addClass('active');
            nullXAxes();
            $("#engagementDaily").hide();
            $("#engagementWeekly").hide();
            $("#engagementMonthly").fadeIn();
            $("#engagementYearly").hide();                
            engGraph.update();
        });
        $("#engagementYear").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'year'
            $(this).addClass('active');
            nullXAxes();
            $("#engagementDaily").hide();
            $("#engagementWeekly").hide();
            $("#engagementMonthly").hide();
            $("#engagementYearly").fadeIn();
            engGraph.update();
        });
        $("#engagementAutoDay").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = null;
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = null;
            $(this).addClass('active');
            engGraph.update();
        });
        $("#engagementAutoWeek").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = null;
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = null;
            $(this).addClass('active');
            engGraph.update();
        });
        $("#engagementAutoMonth").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = null;
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = null;
            $(this).addClass('active');
            engGraph.update();
        });    
        $("#engagementAutoYear").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = null;
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = null;
            $(this).addClass('active');
            engGraph.update();
        });                    
        $("#engagement7Day").click(function(){
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = sevenDays;
            engGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = latestDate;
            $(this).addClass('active');
            engGraph.update();
        });
        //Et Cetera, et cetera
```

Ideally I'd like to turn this into a template which can live in an object within the script's root scope, where I can replace the repeating elements with that chart/graph's name - something like this:

```
var graphTemplate = function(currentGraph, currentGraphShort)
```

and

```
        $("#" + currentGraph + "Daily").hide();
        /////
        [currentGraphShort].options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'day'
```

but my experiments have not worked. I've looked at using Template Literals; but those appear to be more for use in strings (that I can tell, and from what Iv'e used); I've tried creating an object such as `[currentGraphShort]["options"]["scales"]["xAxes[0]"]["time"]["unit"] = 'day'` which also does not work...

Perhaps the solution is something really simple that I'm overlooking, but I'd love a hand with this one!

Thank you =)

Edit:

I've tried adding the exact code I was running as a function in the global root scope, and running it within the function of the graph; but then it is unable to find my graph (engGraph) - saying it is undefined. Perhaps this is also a factor of scope that I'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a global function which looked something like this:

```
    function graphInit(graphName, currentGraph, latestDate) {
    //Date formatting
    var sevenDays = moment(latestDate).subtract(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var thirtyDays = moment(latestDate).subtract(30, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var oneWeek = moment(latestDate).subtract(1, 'weeks').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var twoWeeks = moment(latestDate).subtract(2, 'weeks').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var fourWeeks = moment(latestDate).subtract(4, 'weeks').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var threeMonths = moment(latestDate).subtract(3, 'months').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var sixMonths = moment(latestDate).subtract(6, 'months').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var oneYear = moment(latestDate).subtract(1, 'years').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    var twoYears = moment(latestDate).subtract(2, 'years').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
        //nullify the xAxes scale (Used to default to auto when switching scales)
    function nullXAxes() {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = null;
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = null;
        $(this).addClass('active');
        currentGraph.update();
    }
    //reset the xAxes scale to specified min/max
    function xAxesScale(min, max) {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = min;
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = max;
        $(this).addClass('active');
        currentGraph.update();
    }

    //init scaling
    $("#" + graphName + "Daily,#" + graphName + "Weekly,#" + graphName + "Monthly,#" + graphName + "Yearly").hide();
    //left-side click parameters
    $("#" + graphName + "Auto").click(function() {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = null;
        $("#" + graphName + "Daily,#" + graphName + "Weekly,#" + graphName + "Monthly,#" + graphName + "Yearly").hide();
        nullXAxes();
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "Day").click(function() {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'day'
        $("#" + graphName + "Weekly,#" + graphName + "Monthly,#" + graphName + "Yearly").hide()
        $("#" + graphName + "Daily").fadeIn();
        nullXAxes();
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "Week").click(function() {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'week'
        $("#" + graphName + "Daily,#" + graphName + "Monthly,#" + graphName + "Yearly").hide()
        $("#" + graphName + "Weekly").fadeIn();
        nullXAxes();
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "Month").click(function() {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'month'
        $("#" + graphName + "Daily,#" + graphName + "Weekly,#" + graphName + "Yearly").hide()
        $("#" + graphName + "Monthly").fadeIn();
        nullXAxes();
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "Year").click(function() {
        currentGraph.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.unit = 'year'
        $("#" + graphName + "Daily,#" + graphName + "Weekly,#" + graphName + "Monthly").hide()
        $("#" + graphName + "Yearly").fadeIn();
        nullXAxes();
    });
    //right-side click parameters
    $("#" + graphName + "AutoDay,#" + graphName + "AutoWeek,#" + graphName + "AutoMonth,#" + graphName + "AutoYear").click(function() {
        nullXAxes()
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "7Day").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(sevenDays, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "30Day").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(thirtyDays, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "1Week").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(oneWeek, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "2Week").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(twoWeeks, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "4Week").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(fourWeeks, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "3Month").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(threeMonths, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "6Month").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(sixMonths, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "1Year").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(oneYear, latestDate)
    });
    $("#" + graphName + "2Year").click(function() {
        xAxesScale(twoYears, latestDate)
    });
};
```

And made sure to call the function of graphInit(whateverGraph, currentGraph, latestDate) after we had created the graph, and assigned it a variable (currentGraph). This worked, saved at least 1/4 of the code, and made it far more modular.